# When adding a new property in blender and then export as fbx then when importing to unity the new property not show in unity editor. how to fix?

Tags: unity

In blender I pressed the N key and then on the right side I selected Tools > Workspace > Custom Properties > then clicked on the + New and gave a name to the new property.

Same I did on the side in the Object tab also added new property.

Then saved and in the menu: File > Export > FBX (.fbx) and in the export window I checked the checkbox:  Custom Properties.

but then when dragging the file to the unity editor I see the model but not see the new propety.

[image: blender settings]

and in unity3d editor after importing:
I don't see the new property Fill Amount:

[image: the new property Fill Amount not exist in unity after importing]

Comment: You have to add _Custom Properties_ on the object in the _Object Properties_, not the _Workspace_. And the other thing is: does Unity support custom properties?